# Finding an integer sum in an array of 1 000 000

Tags: c#, sum

Given a large list of integers (more than 1 000 000 values) find how many ways there are of selecting two of them that add up to 0.... Is the question

What I have done is create a positive random integer list:

```
Random pos = new Random();
int POSNO = pos.Next(1, 1000000);
lstPOS.Items.Add(POSNO);
lblPLus.Text = lstPOS.Items.Count.ToString();
POSCount++;
```

And created a negative list:

```
Random neg = new Random();
int NEGNO = neg.Next(100000, 1000000);
lstNEG.Items.Add("-" + NEGNO);
lblNegative.Text = lstNEG.Items.Count.ToString();
NegCount++;
```

To do the sum checking I am using:

```
foreach (var item in lstPOS.Items)
{
    int POSItem = Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString());
    foreach (var negItem in lstNEG.Items)
    {
        int NEGItem = Convert.ToInt32(negItem.ToString());
        int Total = POSItem - NEGItem;
        if (Total == 0)
        {
            lstADD.Items.Add(POSItem + "-" + NEGItem + "=" + Total);
            lblAddition.Text = lstADD.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is not the fastest route. I have considered using an array. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What's the type of `lstPOS` and `lstNEG`?

Comment: I don't think you want to be converting your integers to strings when you put them in the lists.  Why do that?

Comment: lstPOS & lstNEG are simple listboxes. I have used these for visual representation. When I add them to the listbox they are still integers. If I extract from the listbox, will it keep the integer form or change to listbox item?

Comment: Do not forget that *two zeroes* add up *to zero*: `0 + 0 == 0`; so in addition to positives and negatives you have to solve zeroes as a separate case.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see; your array is something like this:

```
  int[] data = new int[] {
    6, -2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, -2
  };
```

you can add up to zero in two different ways:

1. a + (-a) // positive + negative
2. 0 + 0    // any two zeros

in the sample above there're *five* pairs:

```
  -2 + 2 (two pairs): [1] + [3] and [3] + [9]
   0 + 0 (three pairs): [4] + [5], [4] + [8] and [5] + [8]
```

So you have to track positive/negative pairs and zeros. The implementation

```
 Dictionary<int, int> positives = new Dictionary<int, int>();
 Dictionary<int, int> negatives = new Dictionary<int, int>(); 
 int zeros = 0;

 foreach(var item in data) {
   int v;

   if (item < 0) 
     if (negatives.TryGetValue(item, out v))     
       negatives[item] = negatives[item] + 1;
     else
       negatives[item] = 1;  
   else if (item > 0) 
     if (positives.TryGetValue(item, out v))     
       positives[item] = positives[item] + 1;
     else
       positives[item] = 1;  
   else
     zeros += 1;
 } 

 // zeros: binomal coefficent: (2, zeros)
 int result = zeros * (zeros - 1) / 2;

 // positive/negative pairs
 foreach (var p in positives) {
   int n;

   if (negatives.TryGetValue(-p.Key, out n)) 
     result += n * p.Value; 
 } 

 // Test (5)
 Console.Write(result);
```

Note, that there's no sorting, and dictionaries (i.e. *hash tables*) are used for positives and negatives so the execution time will be *linear*, `O(n)`; the dark side of the implementation is that two additional structures (i.e. additional memory) required. In your case (millions integers only - Megabytes) you have that memory.

**Edit: terser, but less readable Linq solution:**

```
  var dict = data
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.Count());

  int result = dict.ContainsKey(0) ? dict[0] * (dict[0] - 1) / 2 : 0;

  result += dict
    .Sum(pair => pair.Key > 0 && dict.ContainsKey(-pair.Key) ? pair.Value * dict[-pair.Key] : 0);
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'm curious if you could review mine as you did with the others, to see if I pass:-) Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest way without sorting!.

First of all you know that the sum of two integers are only 0 when they have **equal absolute** value but one is negative and the other is positive. So you dont need to sort. what you need is to Intersect positive list with negative list (by comparing absolute value). the result is numbers that ended up 0 sum.

Intersect has time complexity of `O(n+m)` where `n` is size of first list and `m` is size of second one.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    int[] positive = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(n => random.Next(1, 1000000)).ToArray();
    int[] negative = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(n => random.Next(-1000000, -1)).ToArray();

    var zeroSum = positive.Intersect(negative, new AbsoluteEqual());

    foreach (var i in zeroSum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = 0", i, i);
    }
}
```

You also need to use this IEqualityComparer.

```
public class AbsoluteEqual : IEqualityComparer<int>
{
    public bool Equals(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x < 0 ? -x : x) == (y < 0 ? -y : y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int obj)
    {
        return obj < 0 ? (-obj).GetHashCode() : obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say `Intersect has time complexity of O(n+m)`?

Comment: Intersect uses hashset. hashset has time complexity of `O(1)` for adding and `O(1)` for removing. you can do a search if you are curious. In the intersect first we create hashset of second list (we add each item of second list so its `O(m)`). then we try to remove each item of first list from hashset (we remove so its `O(n)`). Note that when remove succeeded its considered as intersect. so Intersect is `O(m+n)`. You can also do a search ;) @qxg

Comment: yes, your're right after I checked http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f004df93520c3f7b. But I don't think it support very large data, in which case you may run out of memory. Sort and search algorithm will always work. You have terabytes of data stored in files, you can sort them by merge algorithm and search value as stream. Which solution is better really depends on input size. @GregAdler

Comment: Counter example: `int[] positive = new int[] { 1, 1, 2 };` and `int[] negative = new int[] { -1, -1 };` *four* pairs are expected but *one* actually returned.

Comment: The question is about *how many ways*, so, probably, `zeroSum.Sum()` is expected as a result

Comment: @DmitryBychenko nice catch. i will remove this answer after a minute after i make sure you read this comment!

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary: nothing wrong with the *Linq* solution, but you have to consider *permutations* (as in counter example above); IMHO, `GroupBy()` instead of simple `Intesect()` will solve the problem.

Comment: thanks. how ever if OP consider permutations i would prefer your solution. if i use GroupBy i it wouldnt be fast anymore. @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 1):

You tried to avoid check two numbers that are close (1, 2 are close, 3, 4 are close), but you didn't avoid check like (-100000, 1), (-1, 100000). Time complexity is O(n^2).
To avoid that you need to sort them first, then search from two direction.

```
var random = new Random();
var input = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(_ => random.Next(200) - 100).ToArray();

Array.Sort(input); // This causes most computation. Time Complexity is O(n*log(n));
var expectedSum = 0;
var i = 0;
var j = input.Length - 1;
while (i < j) // This has liner time complexity O(n);
{
    var result = input[i] + input[j];
    if(expectedSum == result)
    {
        var anchori = i;
        while (i < input.Length && input[i] == input[anchori] )
        {
            i++;
        }
        var anchorj = j;
        while (j >= 0 && input[j] == input[anchorj])
        {
            j--;
        }
        // Exclude (self, self) combination
        Func<int, int, int> combination = (n, k) =>
        {
            var mink = k * 2 < n ? k : n - k;
            return mink == 0 ? 1 
                : Enumerable.Range(0, mink).Aggregate(1, (x, y) => x * (n - y)) 
                 / Enumerable.Range(1, mink).Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);
        };
        var c = i < j ? (i - anchori) * (anchorj - j) : combination(i - anchori, 2);
        for (int _ = 0; _ < c; _++)
        {
            // C# 6.0 String.Format
            Console.WriteLine($"{input[anchori]}, {input[anchorj]}");
        }
    }
    else if(result < expectedSum) {
        i++;
    }
    else if(result > expectedSum) {
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: @qxg: Counter Example: `var input = new List<int>() {6, -2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, -2};` *five* pairs are expected while *two* are actually returned.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thanks for the comments. You're right that I didn't handle duplicated input. In that case, just move cursor until current value changes. I've updated my code.

Comment: Edited code *counter example*: `int[] input = new int[] {0, 0};`: `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrwon when `1` is expected

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, I failed your interview:)

Comment: I'll consider combination with self as valid input, but it really depends on requirement. Added more check when two cursors overlap.

Comment: Side note: if you put *C# 6.0* constructions i.e. `$"{input[anchori]}, {input[anchorj]}"` IMHO you should *mention* C# 6.0 requirement (or convert it into `String.Format()`)

Comment: The second edition has the same counter example: `int[] input = new int[] {0, 0};`: *one* pair (`input[0] +input[1] == 0`) is expected when *two* are printed out; in case of *selecting with return* (i.e. `input[0] + input[0] == 0` is allowed) the expected value is *3* ([0] + [0], [0] + [1] and [1] + [1])

Comment: The 3d edit provides an *inconsistent* solution: for `[0, 0]` *four* pairs are returned so I expect *selection with return and ordering*  (`[0] + [0], [0] + [1], [1] + [0], [1] + [1]`) in that case I expect *two* solutions for [-1, 1] input (`[0] + [1]` and `[1] + [0]`) but only *one* is returned (i.e. **no ordering**).

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using (huh) LINQ. Hope the code is self explanatory

First some data

```
var random = new Random();
var data = new int[1000000];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) data[i] = random.Next(-100000, 100000);
```

And now the solution

```
var result = data
    .Where(value => value != int.MinValue)
    .GroupBy(value => Math.Abs(value), (key, values) =>
    {
        if (key == 0)
        {
            var zeroCount = values.Count();
            return zeroCount * (zeroCount - 1) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            int positiveCount = 0, negativeCount = 0;
            foreach (var value in values)
                if (value > 0) positiveCount++; else negativeCount++;
            return positiveCount * negativeCount;
        }
    })
    .Sum();
```

Theoretically the above should have O(N) time and O(M) space complexity, where M is the count of the unique absolute values in the list.

Comment: You've passed, *nice solution*; +1 from me

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you for spending your time looking on this, really appreciate your input.